# How can I make Power Bi detect this as a list?

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I have just created a table in the query editor - (would apply to another query I'm looking to import into Power BI). The table has a column with a list of items and I wanted it to be in such a way that it gets expanded and each item in the list becomes a row - with the initial reference(Coll column). How can I execute that? Thanks!

[image]

EDIT:
Here is how the initial data input looks like

[image: Showing initial input]

And here is the expected output

[image: Expected Output]

For some reason, when I load it this way into Power Query, I don't get it shown as a list, and so that arrow up does not appear so I can click and expand on the values as new rows.

Comment: Share initial input of other table, and desired output based on table above

Comment: @horseyride I have managed to add the necessary edits. Let me know what could be the potential solution. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah massive thanks to this! It did magic. Done that : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set your initial data as a column with items separated by a comma.  In powerquery, right click that column ... split column ...  then choose the delimiter as comma, and specifying rows in Advanced Options

[image]

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(Source, {{"Locations", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Locations")
in  #"Split Column by Delimiter"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WcnRS0lGqjlHyTs2rTIxR0lGIUQpNT8xLgbJDEvOqEvMygbxapVgdoHJniHK/zPTUokyoIveMxDyECl+giuD80pIMBce0oszkRKXYWAA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Teller = _t, Locations = _t]),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(Source,"{","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Locations"}),
    #"Replaced Value1" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value","}","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Locations"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Replaced Value1", {{"Locations", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(", ", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Locations")
in
    #"Split Column by Delimiter"
```

So, first, you need to get rid of the `{` and `}` symbols. You could do it with a GUI replace value button: `#"Replaced Value"` and `#"Replaced Value1"` steps in the M query view.

Next step: Split Column by Delimiter -> Advanced - > Rows. Pick a custom delimiter and put  `,` (space and comma symbol).

That's it.